# Preload Data in collection View

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, wkwebview

I have collection view with WKWebView. One WebView is one page in collection view (cell is fullscreen). Is it possible to load more cells(page) index - 2 to index +2 (I would like to load 2 more cells opposite to the index shown) so that when the user scrolls the content is already loaded and not waiting for the webview to load?

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687205/is-there-a-way-to-preload-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to -preload- UICollectionViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687205/is-there-a-way-to-preload-uicollectionviewcell)